# Convert Char Array toString() return mass

Tags: java, string

I try to reverse a String by

```
1st convert to a Char[]
2nd reverse the Char[]
3rd convert CHar[] back to String by toString() method
```

I've checked the input of toString() is "abcd\0" but the output is "[C@2e686cea" ...

I got two question:

```
1. why toString() output this
2. what's the best way to process String? convert to char[] or using StringBuffer?
```

Here's my code:

```
public class TestBench_1_2 {
    public static String reverseCStr (String str) { 
        if (str == null) return str;
        char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
        int len = str.length();
        char temp = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < (Math.floor((len-1)/2)); ++i) {
            temp = cArray[i];
            cArray[i] = cArray[len-2-i];
            cArray[len-2-i] = temp;
        }
//      String result = new String(cArray);
        String result = cArray.toString();
        return  result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] testStr = {"abcd\0", "abcde\0", "123\0", "ab1p4\0", null};
        System.out.printf("Test Strings: \t\t Reverse Result: \n");
        String temp = null;
        for (String str : testStr) {
            System.out.printf("%s \t\t\t %s\n", str, reverseCStr(str));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's output:

```
Test Strings:            Reverse Result: 
abcd                     [C@2e686cea
abcde                    [C@8e43b44
123                      [C@3feef1eb
ab1p4                    [C@604c9c17
null                     null
```

Answer (score 5):

To convert a `char[]` to a `String`, you should be using `String.valueOf(char[])`.

`char[].toString()`, like all other array implementations, uses the default implementation of `Object.toString()`, which is

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())